# Messing up of content of HTML file

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

If I open my html file directly then whole of the content gets messed up but when I open it through live preview of Brackets then everything is fine. What can be the possible reason? Provided I passed css and javascript file of bootstrap through CDN

Comment: What is directly for you? What is your achitecture? Please share some insight, we can not guess what you want nor can we read minds.

Answer (score 0):

Try hard refreshing the page, `Ctrl + f5`. It clears the cache and shows the most recent version.